# Sending HTML from servlet to js application corrupts data in Firefox

Tags: javascript, json, servlets, mime-types

I'm sending some HTML code back to an iframe using a java servlet and an iframe on the js side.  I'm actually just parsing some json from the HTML code by encasing it in a single `<div>`, using jQuery, but the string that gets sent back sometimes has added text.

If the text that gets added has a word with enclosing angle brackets, Firefox will automatically close the brackets for me, which I don't want.

For example, if I send this:

```
<div>{"location":[],"columns":["<case expression>","headers"]}</div>
```

Firefox (and ONLY Firefox so far, not IE or chrome) will receive it as this:

```
<div>{"location":[],"columns":["<case expression>","headers"]}</case></div>
```

which screws up my parsing.  I'm sending the text with the `Content-Type` of `text/html`, which I think might be causing the issue.  I've tried `Content-Type` of `application/json`, but it won't write html to the iframe unless I'm using the `text/html`.

Can someone help me with a solution?  I'm willing to try a different method of sending the data if it's not too extensive.

Comment: You have to HTML-escape the content at some point before adding the text to the HTML. Characters "<" and ">" are meta-characters and cannot appear just anywhere in HTML; you have to encode them as "&lt;" and "&gt;".

Comment: Can you just send the JSON instead, and then compose the HTML in the JavaScript running on the page?

Comment: @tinyd I'm reading the data by checking a populated iframe, so everything gets written as HTML before I even get a chance to read it.

Comment: @Pointy, Cool, that worked perfectly.  Wana answer so I can give you your due credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to keep the browser from interpreting HTML meta-characters as such, so that your "<" and ">" characters end up as part of the text, you can "escape" them as HTML entities. The "<" character is `&lt;` and the ">" is `&gt;`. People generally also quote the ampersand ("&") as `&amp;` but I think browsers are generally a little smarter about that.

Edit by OP for code solution:

I used `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHTML()`, which worked perfectly.  Thanks!